# Turn ON Flash light every second in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, camera, flashlight

I trying to turn ON the phone flash light every second. I have been searching but nothing found useful.

This is the code that I am using:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

@Override
public void run() {
seconds = 0;
  try {
    while (seconds<11) {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // Put code here!

        seconds++;
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 }
}
};

t.start();
```

I will really appreciate your help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the loop is bad idea.
Try to use handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)

use this at the and of runnable code.